# Green screen in MoviePy

Tags: python, video, moviepy

I'm trying to automate the implementation of some animations in my videos using MoviePy. These animations are played on a green background, so I've been searching for green screen related items on MoviePy. There are not too many results on this Though. However, I did find some code that should work with this. The code that I'm using is the following:

```
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(self.clips, method="compose")
subclip = mpe.vfx.mask_color(subclip, color=[100, 227, 4])
subclip = subclip.resize(height=int(final_clip.h / 2))
subclip = subclip.set_position((final_clip.w / 2 - subclip.w / 2, final_clip.h / 2))
comp = CompositeVideoClip([image_clip, final_clip, subclip.set_start(final_clip.duration / 2)])
```

So, final_clip is every clip stitched together, subclip is the animation on a green screen that I want to display on top somewhere in the middle of the video and comp is the endresult. comp Combines final_clip and subclip and places it on an ImageClip, which serves as background. This all works and gives no errors, but the green in subclip is not gone, it's just the full frame still visible. And I know the RGB color [100, 227, 4] should be correct as I used multiple pieces of software to verify which kind of green it was. So I have subclip, which I want to be half the width and half the height of the video, and placed in the center, but a bit down. The positioning and sizing of the clip is done correctly, it's really just the green that is not being removed here.

I don't get what's wrong here, the samples that I found online use this exact same technique, so if anyone could help me out here, that would be much appreciated!

Also, if anyone knows any hints to speed up the compilation time in MoviePy, that would be a great help as well!

Comment: I wonder if you could use the technique shown [at the end of this blog article](https://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/making-animated-gifs-from-video-files-with-python/) to remove the background, using a threshold and `Scikit Images`. This article is by the author of `MoviePy`.